# How to set JMSCorrelationId and JMSReplyTo header in camel route spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am trying to integrate two systems using messaging queue (Websphere Mq). I have used camel with spring for routing purpose. Now I need to set JMSCorrelationId and JMSReplyTo header in them.

```
      <route id="Request1">
              <from uri="WebMq:queue:inputQ"/>

              <to uri="bean:mycode"/>

              <to uri="WebMq:queue:outputQ"/>

      </route>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://camel.apache.org/constant.html for how to set a contant value, http://camel.apache.org/simple.html for a changing value and otherwise use a processor (a custom class which implements org.camel.Processor) to set headers in it's process method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its useful for the work that I wanted to do. It helps me in request reply scenario.

```
  <route id="Request1">
          <from uri="WebMq:queue:inputQ?replyTo=queue_name pattern="InOut"/>

          <to uri="bean:mycode"/>

          <to uri="WebMq:queue:outputQ"/>

  </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

By placing the following in the middle:

```
<setHeader headerName="JMSCorrelationId">
  <constant>myValue</constant>
</setHeader>
```

You can do the same thing with JMSReplyTo header.

Comment: Its not working for JMS property headers. It only works for custom header. Thats why I am asking a solution for setting JMS Headers. Please guide me correctly if you understand the scenario.

Comment: Looks your issue is related to this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3102
Which version of Camel are you using?

Comment: In short can you try changing the jms endpoint to WebMq:queue:outputQ?preserveMessageQos=true